# Ignore local changes in Firebase snapshot listener

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want my app to sync data and changes between devices. It's easy - you create a snapshot listener and update your data every time it's changing. My problem is that I have a sophisticated local data changes tracking and when snapshot listener fires after I changed something on the very same device, this sophisticated system fails. I'd like to filter out local changes - that were done on the same device - and not get any updates from snapshot listener unless the changes come from somewhere else.

I'm writing an iOS app using Swift if that matters but I believe the principles should be the same for all platforms

Comment: What about attaching metadata changes listener to the snapshot listener. Then checking for the change type from the metadata before applying the changes when snapshot listener is fired. I think hasPendingWrites or something is available and that can be used to check local changes

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude But then I’ll get 2 the listener callback 2 times. One with `hasPendingChanges: true` and one with `false`. I wouldn’t be able to easily determine whether the second one is just a follower of the first one or the actual callback for the remote changes. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

This should be straightforward by using [includeMetadataChanges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#addsnapshotlistenerincludemetadatachanges:listener:) in your listen call and then observing the [isFromCache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/SnapshotMetadata#/c:objc(cs)FIRSnapshotMetadata(py)fromCache) property of the snapshot metadata.

If `isFromCache` is true, that means the change is being propagated locally and is not guaranteed to be server-correct. If `isFromCache` is false, that means it is the acknowledged server value. Since you will be including metadata-only changes in the listen, it will fire even if the server ack is just confirming the already-sent local data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. trying this out I see that if I make local changes I only get updates with `isFromCache: false`. I get that they go to server and server confirms this value but it still doesn't reliably tell me whether this change has been done locally or remotely